# Generating a set of increasing value column headers in R

Tags: r

I'm putting together a script in R to run for a folder of identically formatted data sets.  The goal is to create a new column in the original data frame, run a set of mathematical operations on it, and then copy it to a new data frame.  I'm trying to sort out the simplest way to rename the columns I will be moving over, and I haven't found a way that doesn't require manually changing them all at the end.

The point is to take a set of columns such as: "Sample"
And convert them to: "Sample[n+1]"

I've found this, which is close, but I'm not clear on how to incorporate the increasing value operation:

```
> m2 <- cbind(1,1:4)
> colnames(m2) <- c("x","Y")
> colnames(m2) <- paste("Sub", colnames(m2), sep = "_")
> m2
       Sub_x Sub_Y
>[1,]     1     1
>[2,]     1     2
>[3,]     1     3
>[4,]     1     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attaching indices would work like this:

```
m2 <- cbind(1,1:4)
colnames(m2) <- c("x","Y")
colnames(m2) <- paste( colnames(m2) , seq_along(colnames(m2)) ,  sep = "_")
```

Comment: I had missed that it was intended to be a generic format for attaching indices.  Thank you!